# Get typename from passed in template

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get the typename off a template that is passed into another template? Here is a basic example of what the goal is

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class IntId {
private:
    int id;
public:
    IntId(int id) {
        this->id = id;
    }
};

class StringId {
private:
    std::string id;
public:
    StringId(std::string id) {
        this->id = id;
    }
};

template<typename T_Id>
class Object : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Object<T_Id>>
{
private:
    T_Id id;
public:
    typedef T_Id T;
    Object(T_Id id) {
        this->id = id;
    }
    T_Id getId()
    {
        return this->id;
    }
};


template <class T, class Enable = void>
class Observable {
public:
    // Intentionally doesn't have a set so it breaks the build... I want both types to go into the value below
    void setNonSpecialized(T value) {
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Observable<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Object<IntId>, T>::value>::type> {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<T> value;
    public:
        Observable() {
            value = nullptr;
        };
        void set(std::shared_ptr<T> newValue) {
            this->value = newValue;
        }
};

class UPCObject : public Object<IntId> {

};

class UserObject : public Object<StringId> {

};


int main()
{
    auto upcObject = std::make_shared<UPCObject>();
    auto upcObservable = std::make_shared<Observable<UPCObject>>();
    upcObservable->set(upcObject); // Expected to succeed as UPCObject inherits from Object<IntId> which matches template

    auto userObject = std::make_shared<UserObject>();
    auto userObservable = std::make_shared<Observable<UserObject>>();
    userObservable->set(userObject); // Want this to succeed as UserObject inherits from Object<StringId> which would match template Object<T::T_Id>

    auto intObservable = std::make_shared<Observable<int>>();
    intObservable->setNonSpecialized(0); // Expected to succeed and use the value on non-specialized Observable

    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, upcObject succeeds in it's build because it's type matches the templated type. UserObject doesn't because it has a different Id type.

Now if I change the specialization to the following and explicitly describe the type

```
template <typename T, typename T_Id>
class Observable<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Object<T_Id>, T>::value>::type>
```

I get the build error `'T_Id': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization 'Observable<T,std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Object<T_Id>,T>::value,void>::type>'` because T_Id isn't actually used in Observable at all.

What would be great is if I could do something like the following

```
template <typename T>
class Observable<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Object<T::T_Id>, T>::value>::type>
```

Where I am able to get the T_Id off the type being passed in. Because in this specialization I'm checking the base of Object, it should have a type defined on it.

Comment: "ObjectManager doesn't actually use T_Id I'll get a build error" this statement makes no sense to me. I see nothing obviously wrong with that declaration. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Since ObjectManager's internal code only relies on T and not T_Id the compiler literally outputs the error message I posted. I'm not sure how else to describe that. I can write up a small compliable C++ if that helps get the point across. Apologies for it not being completely verifyable, I thought this would have been a clear "hey you should use this"

Comment: No, there are plenty of declarations of templates in the standard library that never use the template parameters. Case in point `std::void_t`; and there's nothing "clear" about your question, without a [mcve]. Did you read the help center article whose link I just gave you for the second time, and if not why not?

Comment: Updated with a minimal and runnable example. The following two code snippets are things I've tried and failed with.

Comment: Sorry, but your intentions are still quite confusing. You claim that you'd like to do something like, loosely phrased: "`std::is_base_of<Object<T::T_Id>,T>`". However, `Object<T>`'s T_Id is always T, so this really means `std::is_base_of<T,T>`, and this is always true.

Comment: It's always true if the type being passed is based off Object. If instead you wanted to use Observable<int> it would not be true and will be diverted to the `class Enable = void` version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153645/discussion-between-sam-varshavchik-and-k2snowman69).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since you define a typedef in the `Object` class, you can simply do this:

```
template <typename T>
class Observable<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Object<typename T::T>, T>::value>::type>
```

If you were not using that typedef, you could do that:

```
// returning a pointer protect us from abstract types.
template<typename T>
T* get_object_type(const Object<T>&);

template<typename T>
using object_type_t = typename std::remove_pointer<
    decltype(get_object_type(std::declval<const T&>()))
>::type;
```

And then, use the type trait:

```
template <typename T>
class Observable<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<object_type_t<T>, T>::value>::type>
```

Note that sfinae will occur first on `object_type_t`. If the function `get_object_type` is not callable using a `const T&`, that specialization of `Observable` will be ruled out. If `T` don't extends `Object<T>`, but the function `get_object_type` is still callable, then your condition with `is_base_of` will rule out the specialization of `Observable`.

Comment: Thank you!!! The typedef was put there because I found a similar answer but just couldn't get it to work. I was missing the keyword typename!